# Forecasting a non-binomial number

Tags: generalized-linear-model, forecasting, predictive-models, count-data, poisson-regression

I have an ecommerce dataset with revenue, orders, AOV, visits, unique visitors and pageviews for three countries and datasets with just visits, unique visitors and pageviews for 7 countries for the past 600 days. The 7 countries have no ecommerce data because the store does not ship to them. The store is looking into which countries would be most profitable to ship to so I am trying to predict the amount of orders each country could generate based on their visitation.

I was attempting to use the `glm()` function in R with the 3 countries as the training data, but the problem I am encountering is that the outcome has a to be a binomial. Obviously, this wouldn't work for orders.

What function should I use to predict something like this?

Comment: Is it just that your response variable is a count instead of a Bernoulli trial (ie, series of coin flips)? If so, you can still use a GLiM, but the response might be Poisson (perhaps w/ an offset & / or overdispersion).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, but I'm not quite sure I understand.  Doesn't the output of the response variable have to be a 0 or 1?

Comment: A Bernoulli variable (or a binomial w/ n=1) has a 0 or 1 as the only possible outputs. However there are lots of different distributions (the normal is quite common to work w/), and you can use a GLiM to work w/ any response distribution in the exponential family. That includes the normal, the binomial, & (among others) the Poisson. [The Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is the basic distribution for *counts*. If your response variable is a count, you can use a GLiM w/ a Poisson as the response distribution (& the typical link would be the log).

Comment: What's your syntax for `glm`?

Comment: glm(train$sum.of.orders~., family=poisson("log"), data=train)